# Log4j2: Log to a different file if already exists

Tags: java, logging, log4j2

If I run the same Java program multiple times in parallel, they obviously end up using the same log4j configuration. Now, I'd like each process to use an individual log file. I don't care much how they are differentiated (including the process id or a simple counter that increases with the number of already existing files would be enough). Is it possible to do this?

For instance, I'd like to configure the logger as follows:

```
<File name="File" fileName="/tmp/log-%i .log">
    <!-- ... -->
</File>
```

where `%i` is the next available integer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's something I think should do kind of what you want, although I haven't actually tried it. Use a `RollingFile` instead of a `File`, set the triggering policy to `<OnStartupTriggeringPolicy/>`, and set the `filePattern` to a pattern containing %i (or a date and time). The log file for the currently running process will be the `fileName`, but each time the process starts that file will be rolled over to one described by the `filePattern`.